# Image dilation error

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I know its not appropriate to ask questions related to hacker rank here. But this Easy section question is giving me a very hard time and I started to doubt my image processing concepts.

They have given an image

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

and the structuring element as

```
1 0
1 1
```

with the origin as bottom left.

And I got the dilated output as

```
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
```

(Since according to the structuring element, I have to see for bright pixels to origin's top and to right side). I have even verified with Matlab.

> But why hacker rank is not accepting my output ? Or am I missing a
>   core concept of binary image dilation ?

Comment: The dilation output produced in your result using the given structuring element is correct.

Comment: Try to imagine the element overlap the image at each point. If at a certain point there is a `1` on the element that lay on a `1` on the image, there will be a `1` in the output. So your result is correct for the example.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why hacker rank is not accepting this solution or may be I have misunderstood the question in that case its my fault. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dip-morphological-operations-dilation-with-an-irregular-structuring-element

Comment: your answer is flipped.

Comment: @rayryeng I do not agree with you.

Comment: @Adiel I do not agree with your explanation.

Comment: @Shai see my comment to your answer. I tried to explain the `dilation` as in the video, and that is the result. It will be nice if the user can attach the code that gave him this result...

Comment: @Shai our source of confusion most likely came from where the origin of the structuring element is. I didn't run the code in MATLAB so from what I saw I agreed with the output. I guess a visit to the docs is the final arbiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a slightly different result

```
bw = [ 0 0 0 0; 0 1 1 0; 0 0 0 0]; 
imdilate(bw,[1 0;1 1;0 0])

ans =

 0     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0
```

Note that I used a slightly different `strel`: I added a row of zeros at the bottom. I did that in order to adhere to the requirement "origin as bottom left".

I hope this figure explains a bit more:
[image]

As you can see the requirement is that the "origin" of the strel would be the bottom left corner, according to [matlab's `strel` doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel-class.html#inputarg_nhood):

> The center (or origin) of `nhood` is its center element, given by `floor((size(nhood) + 1)/2)`.

In order to have the vertical center in the second row (instead of the first), I added an empty line to the `strel`.

Comment: Please explain with "I did that in order to adhere to the requirement "origin as bottom left"". And how it is different from my approach.

Comment: Thanks now I understood. But I still have one doubt. If we go by the way as described in this video [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8g9WI0y__jU ] the answer seems to be the one which I have got. So please explain how your way and that YouTube videos way are the same thing.

Comment: That is, if we start from the cornet pixel and placing this L shapped strel and check if top pixel or right pixel is 1 only then we set that pixel to 1 else it remains 0. Similarly, we then translate that strel pixel by pixel from left to right and top to bottom.

Comment: @user3243499 my German is not very good, and I tend not to agree with the way this video defined `dilation` operation.

Comment: I think that the result of `dilation` as in the video is what you got in the question.

Comment: @Adiel you can run it in Matlab. I think the root cause for confusion here is the a-symmetry of the `strel`.

Comment: @Shai I agree to that.

Comment: BTW, it seems that first picture in this page-  http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphological-dilation-and-erosion.html   has the same definition as in the video.